# Stop form from submitting until modal is open in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling

I am getting data from a form and on submit button if data ios not valid it returns false and if data is valid am sending an email through ajax in its success method am showing a modal for sent or not I want window.location.href to be change after modal is hidden as form submits before even modal is displayed so I used event.preventdefault to stop it from submit but now have two issues

1. browser gets stuch until modal is open
2. after modal window.location is not being changed.

here is my code for submit button

```
<input type="submit"  class="button btn btn-primary" onclick ="return SendEmail();" />
```

here is SendEmail()

```
function SendEmail()
        {
            if (!CheckContactUsFormValidation()) {
                return false;
            }
            else{
                var l_strEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail').value;
                var l_strComents = document.getElementById('txtComments').value;
                var l_strEventLocation = document.getElementById('txtEventLocation').value;
                var l_strStartDate = document.getElementById('txtStartDate').value;
                var l_strOrganization = document.getElementById('txtOrganization').value;
                var l_strPhone = document.getElementById('txtPhone').value;
                var l_strLastName = document.getElementById('txtLastName').value;
                var l_strFirstName = document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value;
            var rent = document.getElementById("inlineRadio1").value;
            var lease = document.getElementById("inlineRadio2").value;
            if (rent.checked == true) {
                var l_strCheck = 'rent';
            }
            else {
                if (lease.checked == true) {
                    var l_strCheck = 'lease';
                }
            }
            var l_strTitle = "Contact Us";

            var l_strContents = 'Hi, ' + l_strFirstName + ' ' + l_strLastName + '\n';
            l_strContents += 'he is mail for requesting product on ' + l_strCheck + ' and start date is ' + l_strStartDate + ' for organization ' + l_strOrganization + '\n';
            l_strContents += 'his cell #' + l_strPhone + ' and his coments are as follows \n';
            l_strContents += l_strComents + '\n' + 'You can contact him on email: ' + l_strEmail;
            l_strContents += 'End here!';         
            var l_strtoEmail = 'abc@yahoo.com';
            SendEmailWithCustomTitle(l_strtoEmail, l_strContents, l_strTitle);        
        }
        return true;
    }       

    function CheckContactUsFormValidation() {
        var m_boolValidator = true; 

        if (!CheckRequiredFieldValidation('FirstName', 'Enter first name')) {
            m_boolValidator = false;
        } 
        if (!CheckRequiredFieldValidation('LastName', 'Enter last name')) {
            m_boolValidator = false;
        }
        if (!CheckRequiredFieldValidation('Organization', 'Enter Organization')) {
            m_boolValidator = false;
        }
        if (!CheckRequiredFieldValidation('Email', 'Enter Email')) {
            m_boolValidator = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!CheckEmailValidation('Email', 'Enter valid email address')) {
                m_boolValidator = false;
            }
        }
        if (!CheckRequiredFieldValidation('Phone', 'Enter phone#')) {
            m_boolValidator = false;
        }
        if (!CheckRequiredFieldValidation('StartDate', 'Enter start date')) {
            m_boolValidator = false;
        }
        return m_boolValidator;
    }
```

and here is ajax function being called inside SendEmail()

```
function SendEmailWithCustomTitle(txtEmail, txtContents, l_strTitle) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "PTServiceRoutines.aspx/AjaxSendEmail",
    data: "{'p_strEmail':'" + txtEmail + "','p_strTitle':'" + l_strTitle + "','p_strContents':'" + txtContents + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: successAjaxSendEmailWithCustomTitleHandler,
    failure: failureAjaxSendEmailWithCustomTitleHandler,
    error: errorAjaxSendEmailWithCustomTitleHandler
});
return false;
}
function successAjaxSendEmailWithCustomTitleHandler(data) {

    ShowAlert(data.d);


//ShowAlert is method used to open modal showing data.a  
};

function failureAjaxSendEmailWithCustomTitleHandler(data) {
};

function errorAjaxSendEmailWithCustomTitleHandler(data, status) {
};
```

I have already tried event.preventdefault,event.soppropogation but I could not find any easy way to return true from ajax success function SendEmail call.

Comment: congratulation you won **biggest function name badge** :)))

Comment: you are exposing you mail server to some serious email trafic

Comment: where is the modal code for opening the modal ?after the ajax is completed?

Comment: modal is being open from showalert method @madalinivascu

Comment: so you do the ajax->open the modal->user closes the modal->redirect , yes?

Comment: @madalinivascu yes I want it in that way and browser should not stuck during this

Comment: where is it getting stuck?

Comment: when control moves inside SendEmailWithCustomTitle() until modal is open.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `async:false,` from you ajax to stop the browser from waiting for the ajax to complete

Use the following event to redirect when the modal is closed

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   window.location.href = "desired-page.php"
})
```

Comment: second part want to use window.location.href when modal dismiss and I don't have modal id.

Comment: you need a click event on the dismiss button of the modal

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button in modal and in that button click event, at first hide the modal and the call the ajax call. And `window.location.href` will not work inside a html form. To make `window.location.href` work you can move your submit button out of the form.

To open modal in success follow one of following two methods.

```
.done(function() {
  $("#yourmodal").modal();
});
```

Or

```
success: function(data) {
        $("#yourmodal").modal();
    }
```

To stop ajax call until modal hide use following. Place your ajax call inside a function for an example "submitForm()". call this in following.

```
 $('#yourmodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      // do something...
    })
```

Comment: modal is being open ajax success mean to say I required to open modal inside success method

Comment: Edited the post try it might help you

Comment: modal is already being open by showalert(data.a); I need to stop form from sumitting until modal is open and during that browser should niot stuck.